# Column names with line breaks

Tags: postgresql

I know that for text strings in PostgreSQL line breaks are unified by appending symbol `E` or `e` in front of the text:

```
SELECT E'first\nsecond'
```

results in:

```
first
second
```

But PostgreSQL also support line breaks within column names - not sure why or how evil this practice is, but one can do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE One("first\nsecond" text);
CREATE TABLE Two("first
second" text);
```

When you are unfortunate enough to run into one of these, you would find that while these queries work:

```
SELECT "first\nsecond" from One;
SELECT "first
second" from Two;
```

these ones do not:

```
SELECT "first
second" from One;
SELECT "first\nsecond" from Two;
```

My question is: Is there a way in PostgreSQL that unifies such differences, similar to the situation with the column values?

I have tried putting `E` in front of `"first\nsecond"` column names, but it is not supported. Trying to put `\r\n` instead (I'm using Windows) gave me a third type of column names, one that can only be queried as:

```
SELECT "first\r\nsecond" FROM Third
```

Comment: I guess the actual newline that is send to the server depends on your SQL client. Maybe those with the "visible" newline is in fact a Windows/DOS newline (using `\r\n` instead of `\n`)?

Comment: I am using pgAdmin 1.18.1 under Windows 10, and I have tried using `\r\n` instead of `\n`, which gave a third type of column names. Question updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Column names are identifiers, and the gory details of the syntax for identifiers are described at:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

**TL;DR**: use the `U&"..."` syntax to inject non-printable characters into identifiers through their Unicode codepoints, and there's no way to unify `CR,LF` with `LF` alone.

### How to refer to the column in a single line

We're allowed to use Unicode escape sequences in identifiers, so per documentation, the following does work:

```
select U&"first\000asecond" from Two;
```

if it's just a newline character between the two words.

### What happens with the queries on the first table

The table is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE One("first\nsecond" text);
```

As the backslash character has no special meaning here, this column does not contain any newline.
It contains `first` followed by `\` followed by `n` followed by `second`.
So:

```
 SELECT "first\nsecond" from One;
```

does work because it's the same as what's in the `CREATE TABLE`

whereas

```
SELECT "first
second" from One;
```

fails because there's a newline in that SELECT where the actual column name in the table has a backslash followed by a `n`.

### What happens with the queries on the second table

This is the opposite of "One".

```
CREATE TABLE Two("first
second" text);
```

The newline is taken verbatim and is part of the column.
So

```
SELECT "first
second" from Two;
```

works because the newline is there exactly as in the CREATE TABLE,
with an embedded newline,
whereas

```
SELECT "first\nsecond" from Two;
```

fails because as previously `\n` in this context does not mean a newline.

### Carriage Return followed by Newline, or anything weirder

As mentioned in comments and your edit, this could be carriage return and newline instead, in which case the following should do:

```
select U&"first\000d\000asecond" from Two;
```

although in my test, hitting Enter in the middle of a column with `psql` on Unix and Windows has the same effect: a single newline in the column's name.

To check what exact characters ended up in a column name, we can inspect them in hexadecimal.

When applied to your create table example, from inside psql under Unix:

```
CREATE TABLE Two("first
second" text);

select convert_to(column_name::text,'UTF-8')
 from information_schema.columns 
 where table_schema='public'
   and table_name='two';
```

The result is:

```
        convert_to         
----------------------------
 \x66697273740a7365636f6e64
```

For more complex cases (e.g. non-ascii characters with several bytes in UTF-8), a more advanced query might help, for easy-to-read codepoints:

```
select c,lpad(to_hex(ascii(c)),4,'0') from (
  select regexp_split_to_table(column_name::text,'')  as c
    from  information_schema.columns
    where table_schema='public'
    and table_name='two'
  ) as g;

 c | lpad 
---+------
 f | 0066
 i | 0069
 r | 0072
 s | 0073
 t | 0074
  +| 000a
   | 
 s | 0073
 e | 0065
 c | 0063
 o | 006f
 n | 006e
 d | 0064
```

Comment: So if I have a line break within the column name, how should it be converted into a single-line name, so it would work the same on every OS? That's mainly what I want to understand.

Comment: @vitaly-t: not sure whether you're asking how to remove the undesirable chars in the middle of the column, or how to deal with them without removing them. If you wish to refer to the column the same way whichever \n or \r\n lies in the middle, I'd say it's not possible.

Comment: Anyway if I fire up psql on windows and hit the Enter key in the middle of my column definition, i get \n, not \r\n

Comment: Say, you are parsing a column name, and encounter a line break symbol (depending on the OS). Is there a universally usable way to convert such names into a single-line ones that would be recognized by the server as the same?

Comment: @vitaly-t: personally I think that no, there's no way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/238814/daniel-v%c3%a9rit%c3%a9, I can see that the right answer is - No, it is not possible, but then your answer would need to be updated accordingly, to be accepted.